# Regarding the process status on output of /proc/stat command

Tags: linux, proc, stat

When I check the process status output of my process thru /proc//stat then got to know mostly it is in "D" state which means Unterrptible sleep. I understand it is doing some operation which cannot be interrupted but could someone help me on listing what all are the operations includes in this IO/Uninterruptible sleep ?

Any link also would be fine to understand.

D Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R Running or runnable (on run queue)
S Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
W paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X dead (should never be seen)
Z Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's proably disk I/O some (slow) calls can return EINTR eg) read waiting for keyboard input from tty.  Fast system calls won't get interrupted by signals.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62693/why-uninterruptible-sleep-is-not-counted-as-idle

More info about uninterruptible sleep at Wiki [Sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28system_call%29)
This page shows how you can induce this state using vfork(2) [disown, zombie children, and the uninterruptible sleep](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/disown_zombie_children_and_the)
Some support info from Novell [Processes in an Uninterruptible Sleep (D) State](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002725)

Comment: Thanks for the quick prompt. The second link (Novell) really helps on debugging it further. In my system, we dont have disk instead all the FS are NFS mounted and mostly I don't suspect it got stuck/stalled in the file operation but could see higher number spent in poll_schedule_timeout...

Comment: NFS tries hard to emulate local disks, so from your program's point of view open/read/write/close need to be as like local disk I/O as possible.  As the other answer points out, on NFS R/W filesystemss should be hard mounted, interrupting is avoided to reduce data loss, R/O systems may be soft mounted in which case SIG's can cause interrupted calls.  Didn't have much time to go beyond the basics, if answers help it's NICE if you vote for them, so we gain points for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

A process goes into uninterruptible sleep when it makes IO request (it can be disk, network and etc.) and wait for completion of the request. Usually a high number (more than 5-6 for example; of course it depends) of processes in D state indicate that there might be some serious problem that needs to be addressed.

The following cases are the ones which come to my mind as reasons for many processes in D state:

- If you lose connection to NFS server. All processes performing some IO on the NFS server will go into D state. Note that slow operations on the NFS server (caused by issues with server's disks/RAID array) might also cause large number of processes in D state on the client, even with healthy network connection between the client and the server.
- You have a faulty disk/RAID array which slows down reads/writes due to bad sectors for example. That's why there are "RAID edition" disks which help to alleviate such issues (more info at [Error recovery control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control));

Good hint about what is the reason for the sleep can be given by the `wchan` specifier of the `ps` command:

`ps -eo ppid,pid,user,stat,pcpu,comm,wchan`

and more specifically, the `wchan` specifier shows the following information ([man ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)):

`name of the kernel function in which the process is sleeping, a "-" if the process is running, or a "*" if the process is multi-threaded and ps is not displaying threads.`

Comment: Thanks for the quick prompt. When I observed the process is mostly under D state the wchan mostly reported poll_schedule_timeout and other half 0 .. had few number for do_page_fault as well.. This process doesnt do much against the socket operation as everything is offloaded to different process which is hard affined to another core.. Is there any specific way to understand whether NFS read/Write is leading to this process in D state for long time ? On more observation was the process user space CPU occupancy was ~50% and system space occupancy was ~20 % (not sure why more time here.).Thx.

Comment: You can try to `strace` the process and see on which syscalls there are delays. Unfortunately detecting NFS problems is quite painful sometimes. First, you can check on the server and monitor it for high `%util` field in `iostat -x 1`. It should not go above 90% frequently. Also, there should be no many `nfsd` processes in D state. On the client side you can use something like `while true; do nfsstat -rc; sleep 2; done` and monitor for retransmissions (`retrans`), which may indicate issue with the network.

Comment: Thanks .. 
Strace is not possible against that process because it is handling lot of exceptions to virtulize the processor. When I attempt to attach strace the process went for restart. I am in process of getting iostat rpm for PPC arch. I quickly monitored the nfsstat and below is the output in which the the call count is increasing and retrans is not changed throughout the monitored period.  

 
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
296698     1384       57